# "Запомнить меня" - авторизация на сайте

Tags: веб-сервер, java

Добрый день. 
Какие есть варианты с автоматической авторизацией, как сделать фичу "запомнить меня"?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно сделать табличку примерного содержания:

`id | token1 | token2 | user_id`

Когда пользователь нажал запомнить меня то мы делаем запись в таблицу и устанавливаем куку (например: с именем auto и значением - token1:token2
Где token1 и token2 md5 (или другая хеш функция) от Random + время (например)

В следующий раз когда пользователь заходит на сайт (основная авторизация не прошла) Подымаем его куку auto и ищем в таблице запись: `where token1=autoCookie.split(":")[0]` (это псевдокод разумеется, думаю основную идею вы поняли)

И Если запись найдена и `token2=autoCookie.split(":")[1]` то авторизируем пользователя и меняем token2 на другое сгенерированное значение. Если же запись найдена, но token2 не равен ожидаемому, то следует удалить запись  с `token1 = autoCookie.split(":")[0]` Это в некоторой степени защита от перехвата кук. В таком случае автоматической авторизации лишатся оба, и "злоумышленник" и "пользователь"

Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный способ это использование [HTTP cookie](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). Поскольку речь идет о Java, то JSP и сервлеты поддерживают высокоуровневый API работы с кукисами.

Пример использования кукисов при работе с сервлетами [приведен здесь](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Cookies.html)